# Redirect 'go get' to use SOCKS

Tags: go, socks

I need proxy to download packages from golang.org. I have a SOCKS server myself, and need to direct 'go get' to connect through it. But I've tried tsocks and proxychains and they both don't help. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Perhaps also useful: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GoGetProxyConfig

Comment: @TimCooper Thanks for your first link! In fact I've looked at that question but didn't read the comments carefully:).  Anyway, privoxy is exactly what I need.